# Query fast in latin1, slow in utf8 - why?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, join

I have a query that goes something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT table1.id, {long list of fields} FROM table1 
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id 
     {... more joins ...} 
     LEFT JOIN table_last ON table_last.id=some_table.last_id
     WHERE ( table_last.id IS NULL) AND {...more conditions...}
     ORDER BY table1.date_entered desc LIMIT 0,6
```

This query on the same database runs fine (<1s runtime) when run with latin1 as client charset, and is extremely slow (couldn't wait for it to finish) after `SET NAMES 'utf8'`. The query returns 70 rows (the part before the limit, of course), so the result set size should not be a problem. I checked all tables in all joins and they all seem to have UTF-8 as their charset (I checked with `SHOW TABLE CREATE`).

What could cause such strange behavior? How utf8 in this case is so much worse that latin1?
In case it's relevant, the ID field are `char(36)` everywhere, and joins have conditions based on such fields and integer fields and varchar fields.

P.S. I know `DISTINCT` can take time, but I can't remove it and it's 70 rows anyway and it *is* fast on default (latin1) setting! So it looks like something external to the query, but what?

Comment: What collations are your tables in?

Comment: @Pekka: utf8_general_ci I think

Comment: Which database are you using? Though, I'm with Pekka - this looks like a collation related issue

Comment: @StasM you think or you're sure? :)

Comment: @blueberryfields mysql, see the tags ;)

Comment: @Pekka that's what phpmyadmin is saying

Comment: Why are you performing the conversion from utf8 to utf8?

Comment: @StasM fair enough. Then I don't understand it either. I would have understood if it would have to do some massive character set conversions but if the tables are utf8 as well, `SET NAMES utf8` should, if anything, speed it up. Strange. This is on a local machine?

Comment: @blueberryfields I don't perform any conversion. I just run the query from command like. If I run it with default settings, it's fast. If I do `set names 'utf8'` before it (as my web applications does) is it slow.

Comment: @Pekka yes, reproducible from CLI client on the DB server.

Comment: @StasM no complicated function calls in your conditions?

Comment: @Pekka: one function on return fields: `CONCAT(IFNULL(sometable.first_name,''),' ',IFNULL(sometable.last_name,'')) user_name`. Besides that, no calls in conditions, only comparing fields to other fields and to constants (integer or string).

Comment: @StasM right. Can't see that slowing down things. Hmm. If nothing comes of it here, maybe ask on serverfault.com

Comment: which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 0):

When you table us using `utf8` it allocates 3x the length of a *varchar* for each row (256 * 3 = 768 bytes)!

This will mean that your queries use up more resources now that the strings take up three times the space - so buffers aren't as big and you may have to swap out if there are many queries going on at the same time - this would further degrade your query/server's performance.

Comment: This still doesn't explain the issue. The tables are UTF-8 in any case, it's just the *connection* collation that changes.